# ASP.Net Learning

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

Hi i am trying to build a website usign ASP.NET what is the best resource or way to learn it?

Also do i need DotNetNuke or something similar to manage my project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend staying far, far away from DotNetNuke, or any CMS for that matter. If your goal is to learn the language then getting tangled up in a [horrible] CMS will only make it harder on you.

Comment: Apparently somebody thinks DotNetNuke is good... If that isn't it, perhaps you should comment why you down voted. Personally, I do all my work in a homebrew CMS and I love it, but it is definitely not a good place for a beginner to start learning.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, DotNetNuke would be overkill and will likely confuse you more than help as they have implemented many advanced designs to make it as modular as possible. I.e., it will not be clear why they are doing things the way they are.

The simplest means to learn is to do it. Create a regular ASP.NET site for some personal or non-critical purpose. In terms of resources, there are plenty on the Internet of course beyond search. Here are a few:

- [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/)
- [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/default.aspx)
- [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx)

In addition to stuff on the Internet, I would read lots of books. You can either purchase them individually or you could look at an online resource which allows you read many such as [Books 24x7](http://www.books24x7.com/) or [Safari Books](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The official site is a good start: http://www.asp.net/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn is to do.  Begin a website, and when you run into a problem you can't fix or figure out, check here or the sites others mentioned.  I find books useful as references while I am working on a project but not as useful for reading straight through.

I also like [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com) when I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke is an open source Content Management system (CMS). I would first learn ASP.Net. Try creating some sample web sites. As Thomas has rightly pointed out that DotNetNuke is an overkill.